# Copying one file to multiple directories

Tags: bash, shell-script, files, wildcards, cp

I have a file that I want to copy to another 60 directories.

The best way I can think of doing this is by making a bash script that has instructions to every folder like this:

```
cp script.sh /home/user/dl/*/111/23
cp script.sh /home/user/dl/*/111/23
cp script.sh /home/user/dl/*/111/23
and so on...
```

The * is a number starting at 1 and finishing at 60

There has to be a better way than this.

Answer (score 8):

```
for((i=1;i<61;i++)); do
  cp -p script.sh /home/user/dl/${i}/111/23
done
```

Or, more fun:

```
eval "cp script.sh /home/user/dl/"{1..60}"/111/23;"
```

Comment: i do not think the `eval` option works, since `cp` takes only one directory at a time as target

Comment: @1_CR Giving a try (with `echo`, of course) is often better than just thinking...

Comment: yes, actually works, sorry had used single quotes instead of double

Comment: @1_CR Doesn't make a difference, does it? There's nothing to expand in the quoted string. The mistake must have been something different.

Comment: I had used something like this `eval "cp script.sh "'dl/{1..10}'"/23/;"`. Got lazy and modified a previous example i was trying out instead of copying yours verbatim

Answer (score 5):

with `bash` and `xargs`

```
printf "%s\n" /home/user/dl/{1..60}/111/23/ | xargs -n 1 cp script.sh
```

Comment: What's more, you could use xargs' `-P` option to execute in parallel, which could give a good speed-up depending on how the target directories are distributed on the underlying filesystem(s).